# How to encrypt and decrypt image using DES using pycrypto library in python 3?

Tags: python-3.x, image, encryption, pycrypto, des

This is the code that I have tried for text encryption and decryption:

```
from Crypto.Cipher import DES
from Crypto import Random

def pad(text):
    while len(text) % 8 != 0:
        text += " "
    return text

def removepad(text):
    reverse = text[::-1]
    for i in range(len(text)):
        if reverse[i] == ' ':
            pass
        else:
            break
    text = reverse[i:]
    text = text[::-1]
    return text

# plaintext = input("Enter Plaintext: ")
# key = input("Enter Key:")
plaintext = 'Encryption and Decryption of DES for OFB mode'
key = 'hellokey'
print("Plaintext: ",plaintext)
print("Key: ",key)
print()

iv = Random.new().read(DES.block_size)
cipher = DES.new(key, DES.MODE_OFB, iv)

plaintext = pad(plaintext)
msg = iv + cipher.encrypt(plaintext)
print("Encrypted Text: ")
print(msg)
print()

decCipher = DES.new(key, DES.MODE_OFB, msg[:DES.block_size])
msgback = decCipher.decrypt(msg[DES.block_size:])
dmsg = removepad(msgback.decode("utf-8"))
print("Decrypted Text: ")
print(dmsg)
```

This is the output for above code:

Plaintext:  Encryption and Decryption of DES for OFB mode
Key:  hellokey

Encrypted Text:
b'\xd5\xc5$\xdc\xac=4*\x91\xfa\x8c\x14\xe7\xbf\xb8\xd6a\x99<\xca\x132\x8d\xa3Q\xfd\xdf\x9cDQ\xd4\xd4e\xc3\xde"4x<\xa0\x8d\x11\x80\x97g:\xdam\x8a\xdfl\xcbaxu\xbe'

Decrypted Text:
Encryption and Decryption of DES for OFB mode

Comment: Both DES and PyCrypto are outdated and insecure. You should therefore use e.g. AES and PyCryptodome (the latter also supports padding with the `Crypto.Util.Padding` module). Encrypted are always bytes, whether these are interpreted as text using a particular encoding or as an image format (like jpg or bmp) is irrelevant for the encryption itself. But an image would probably be loaded from a file because of the data volume and the encrypted data would be stored in a file.

Answer (score 2):

Regardless of whether you have to use DES, `DES.new(key, ...)` expects a *bytes* `key` and `cipher.encrypt(plaintext)` expects a *bytes* `plaintext` rather than `str` ones, so use *bytes* literals `key = b'hellokey'` or encode to *bytes* `msg = iv + cipher.encrypt(plaintext.encode())`.